# Position of saved form data in a WPF Webbrowser Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

We use a webbrowser control in a sidebar  of our WPF application. The Webbrowser shows a login mask. If the user clicks on the input textbox, the browser shows the saved formdata (username from previous logins) on the wrong position. It's not showing up under the textbox, like expected.Sometimes not even in the application window. How can we fix the position of the saved form data?  Is there a way? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide your code, so that we are able to help you.

Comment: It is just a simple browser in a dynamics:DynamicsBaseHostedControl: <dynamics:DynamicsBaseHostedControl>....<grid>
 <WebBrowser x:Name="WebBrowser" /></grid>
</dynamics:DynamicsBaseHostedControl>